# Using OnClientClick to open a chart window fails after the first use

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2015 with Windows10 and C#. My app has 4 options, all of which execute serially in the same window, displaying output in a gridview; some options also display a button that charts a selected row in a separate window.
Switching between options works fine, and the first time that I chart works fine. My problem is that when I close the chart window, run other options, then come back to one that charts, the button click fails. A window is displayed with the chart icon so OnClientClick appears to have run, but OnClick never executes and the chart is not filled.

I know no Java so do not know how to debug it. Can someone please suggest a fix or an alternative that does not use Java!

Here is the critical code in the button click.

```
<asp:Button 
   ID="GoChart" 
   CssClass="button" 
   runat="server" 
   Text="Select, then Chart" 
   Visible="false" 
   Style="border-radius: 0.4em; width: 9em; float: left; margin-left: 1px; color: white;" 
   ToolTip="Select a row in the grid, then click here to chart the row. " 
   OnClick="GoChart_Click1" 
   OnClientClick="window.open('NewChart.aspx','_blank');return false"/>
```

On the second use of the chart button, GoChart_Click1 is never reached.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't tag something as Java if you're asking for a solution specifically not in Java.

Comment: I think you mean javascript. You need to post the code you are using to create the object and also to handle the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `GoChart_Click1` should actually never be executed because in the `OnClientClick` you return false signaling the browser to not execute the default behaviour of the button which would be to call `GoChart_Click1`.

Remove the `return false;` so that `GoChart_Click1` is executed.

However, I don't think this will solve your problem since I don't see how you could do something with the newly opened window from within `GoChart_Click1`.

I suppose you need to share the source of `GoChart_Click1` and the source of `NewChart.aspx` to get a more detailed answer.

I suppose that whatever code you have in `GoChart_Click1` that fills the chart would be better placed in the load event in `NewChart.aspx.cs` directly.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
OnClientClick="window.open('NewChart.aspx','_blank');return false"
```

To

```
OnClientClick="window.open('NewChart.aspx','_blank');"
```

Return false will stop the service side Click of the button. If you want service side action to be executed after Client Click remove the `return false` part.

Comment: Thanks, but "return false" opens the chart window, leaving the original window intact, so that when I close it I can go back to the grid and select another row to chart. If I remove "return false", the chart window replaces the original. 
GoChart_Click1 simply contains 
Response.Redirect("~/NewChart.aspx");

Comment: Thanks, you are right, GoChart_Click1 is never executed. 
"return false" loads a new window, leaving the original intact, so I can return to the grid to chart another row. If I remove it, the chart window replaces the original, and I lose the grid. 
After the first pass GoChart_Click1 does not find Page_Load of NewChart.aspx.cs where the chart is filled,  so I get a blank window with a chart icon, and no chart. Why would successive use of Go_Chart1 not reach  NewChart.aspx.cs 

Thank you very much for helping me to better understand OnClientClick!

Comment: @petergregory you are welcome you can mark the question as correct

Comment: It's brower related; both Chrome and Firefox execute correctly, IE 11 is the problem. As I am new to StackOverflow, how do you mark answers; I see up/down arrows that offer 1 or 2. and do I mark both correct answers, or only 1?